# How display more than one diagram in main page in Enterprise Architect

Tags: diagram, enterprise, enterprise-architect

How can i display many diagrams in home page and swap between them in Enterprise Architect.
I can display only one diagram and when i open another diagram ,this diagram take place of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the tab with the name of the diagram. The window will float free and you can dock it elsewhere.

[image]

Click and drag in the green marked area.

Comment: I can't do this , can you explain me what should i do ? i can't drag the first diagram .

Comment: @MSc. do you mean projects? The recent section on the start page denotes EA projects

Comment: Here's a small tutorial on getting some basics down on EA http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/introduction/quick_start.html

Comment: Although EA is consistently inconsistent, this works a charm with (almost?) all windows in EA.

Comment: Yes I mean projects, and thank you very much, I see this tutorial is good.

Comment: @MSc. in that case you cant really have 2 projects open in the same "window", they will open separately in their own windows

Comment: @ThomasKilian "EA is consitently inconsistent" should be on the front page of EA, also, I know that package "View as list" and diagrams " View as list" dont persist even if you set them in a workspace

Comment: @MartinGrégoire If that were the only inconsistency I'd be more than happy ;-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian I was referring to how the floating windows "work like a charm" in EA

Comment: @MartinGrégoire Honestly, this is one of the rare implementation details where EA is (very) consistent and which has a nice user interaction design. But that are so many bells and whistles which just produce a cacophony.